# How to change CSS of table row (tr) in a table based on dynamic div?

Tags: jquery

#### Problem:

In a table, some of the cells will get dynamic rows , once I got the dynamic rows how can I change the css of row?

Simply i want to change `vertical-align: bottom` for the entire table row.

Is it possible in jQuery?

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Providing code snippet is always helpful.What event causes the cells to get dynamic rows?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery will do this yes:

```
$(".RowsFound").addClass('CssClassToAdd');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: actually my problem is i would like to show one message in one of the cell in table. by default all elements in table are aligned as top position. if i add one div in any cell on top of the control, then alignment problem is coming. so what i would like to want, when the div is apper that time i want to do the alignment of entire row to bottom. is is possible or not? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.NewRows').css('vertical-align','bottom');
```

Comment: hi thans for updating. the issue is -- when the document is loaded first time the divs (having class="myclass") are in visibility hidden. when i do post back that time i want to change the alignment of controls to bottom.is it possible?

Comment: With that bit of jQuery you can change any css property of any element on your page.  You have not shown a code sample, so you'll need to figure out on your own when and to what element you need to apply the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try margin:0 auto; on the DIV's css. I dont think you can vertical align the div inside the TD. vertical-align, as far as I know only affects the direct text or image.